# What is this bibstyle? Can anyone point out?

Tags: latex

I'm formatting my journal paper and they want bibliography to be in this format.
eg.

References:

> Lou T, Tang J (2013) Mining structural hole spanners through information diffusion in social networks. In: Proceedings of the 22nd
>   international conference on World Wide Web. ACM, 2013, pp
>   825–836

I have tried using all `natbib` styles:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

but couldn't get the Year next to authors name.

What I get is year at the end.

> Lou T, Tang J  Mining structural hole spanners through information diffusion in social networks. In: Proceedings of the 22nd
>   international conference on World Wide Web. ACM, 2013, pp
>   825–836 (2013)

Comment: To which journal do you want submit your article?

Comment: See here for pointers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles